# Is this breathing indication unclear?

Tags: breathing, choral, phrasing

These are a few snippets from an elementary chorus piece "Storm" by James Desjardins, published by BriLee music.  This first breathing indication is clear.  There is no punctuation after *roar*, and dashed slur indicates to me that the singers should not breathe before *gathering* and carry the phrase through.  Easy.

[image]

I have always taught them to breathe when they see a comma or period after a word in the lyrics.  I *thought* this was the convention.  They were puzzled by this (below), which seems contradictory.  The two snapshots appear one on top of the other on the screen; they are consecutive measures but separated by a page break.

[image]
[image]

*Elements* has a period after it, which I thought means take a breath.  But the slur also shows to carry the phrase.  Further, the kids have no difficulty singing this through without a breath.

**Is the period after *element* a misprint?

Comment: There's no way to answer the question about the no-breath or period being correct/incorrect without seeing either more of the text or, better, knowing the original source of the text — at least include the title of the piece. Otherwise, the only interpretation is that the composer doesn't want a breath at the end of this particular sentence, but the "why" cannot be determined.

Comment: Sorry - I edited it just now after forgetting the title.  The text is the composer's own, so there is no additional source for that.

Comment: @Aaron A watermarked version of the score can be found at https://www.brileemusic.com/bl1063-storm.html

Comment: @ElementsInSpace Thanks. I also found a PDF copy.

Comment: @ElementsInSpace How is it that there are schools that don't know it's not cool to post a published work as a PDF?

Comment: Does the use of three notes for the two-syllable word ‘rumbling’ confuse anyone else?  I expect the author wants it to be pronounced as three syllables, but I'd find it easier to read if it were written that way (e.g. ‘rum-bul-ing’).

Comment: Isn't it more usual to indicate singing through with no breath by an extended underscore in the lyrics?  The dotted slur looks too much like a slide to me.

Answer (score 5):

Both the period after "elements" and the breath mark between "elements" and "Clouds" are correct.

The structure set up in the previous two phrases is a breath every four measures. Desjardins wants to preserve that, which means taking no breath after "elements". Thus, the no-breath mark is there to clarify that the usual "breath at the period" convention does not apply in that instance.

The phrasing is of particular importance, because after three four-bar phrases (of which "elements. Clouds" is the third") there is a five-bar phrase. Observing the period after "elements" would undercut the impact of the five-bar phrase by changing the phrase structure early.

Comment: So, am I wrong in advising students to breathe at punctuation?  Or is that a thing, but the obvious phrasing needs here and the no-breath mark supercede it?

Comment: You're not wrong. Breathing at punctation is a good rule of thumb, but it's not rigid, and this case is an exception.

Comment: Righto.  Obviously here a breath would sound terrible...

Comment: To put it another way: punctuation shows where breaks make sense linguistically. Breathing indications show where breaks make sense musically. Often the two coincide, so you'll breathe where there's punctuation, and there's no need for any breathing instructions; occasionally they don't, so the composer can insert breathing indications to show what makes sense musically.

Answer (score 0):

For declamatory purposes it is a good rule of thumb to add a caesura when encountering a linguistic caesura, which usually happens at periods and commas. This makes sense, as usually a well composed vocal piece will follow the mode of speaking. But this does not mean that this is always the case. There may be many reasons why not to do this — e.g. maybe you simply to not want to follow the language, but just create a big legato choral "pad".

In this case it is a very simple reason: It would not really work out otherwise. The section is musically made up of linked phrases: The phrase over the elements leads to the next phrase. This means it is musically weird to put a stop there. This also means the the elements ends on 6. Unless you have a really slow tempo it is pretty hard to find space for a caesura there (and almost impossible without sacrificing quality on the -ments). Usually the would be the time where you prepare the aviso for the next phrase.

So this is a place where you need to sacrifice this declamatory rule for reasons of musicality and and feasibility.